# Button not clickable inside the OverflowBox Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have this view where I have a rectangular box in a column and inside I have a text and a button, so I want the button to be clickable, I have wrapped the whole thing inside the OverflowBox. I have tried and tested to come with a solution and even when I debug, I cannot find anything. My suspicion is that maybe it is affected by the OverflowBox, the OverflowBox helps me with the design I want. Here is my code below:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Container(
      width: 311,
      height: 141,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 12.09,
        left: 16.59,
        right: 220.47,
        bottom: 60,
      ),
      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
        color: SuperSportColorScheme.black,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: BorderSide(
            width: 1,
            color: SuperSportColorScheme.white
                .withOpacity(0.10000000149011612),
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
        ),
      ),
      child: OverflowBox(
        maxHeight: double.infinity,
        maxWidth: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 40,
              ),
              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                dstv_stream_icon,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 12,
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 200,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Get all the sports that matters\non DStv Stream.',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: SuperSportColorScheme.white,
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 12,
            ),
            //this is where the code for the button starts
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 200),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  _launchDstvStreamURL();
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 203,
                  height: 40,
                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                    color: const Color(0xFF75FBEB),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: const Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                        child: Text(
                          'Buy DStv Stream',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: SuperSportColorScheme.black,
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            height: 0.08,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

So, can you guys please assist by looking at my code at where am I getting it wrong, why my button inside cannot be clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the `OverflowBox` that is restricting the tap of your button.

The `OverflowBox` widget is not commonly used for layouts, and your component can be implemented without it:

```dart
Container(
  width: 311,
  height: 141,
  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
    color: Colors.black,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      side: BorderSide(
        width: 1,
        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.10000000149011612),
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
    ),
  ),
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
      const SizedBox(height: 12),
      const Text(
        'Get all the sports that matters\non DStv Stream.',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 12,
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 12),
      //this is where the code for the button starts
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print('a');
        },
        child: DecoratedBox(
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            color: const Color(0xFF75FBEB),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
            ),
          ),
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40, vertical: 15),
            child: Text(
              'Buy DStv Stream',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 14,
                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                height: 0.08,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Here's how the above code looks, with the button now clickable:

[image]

You can use the `Align` widget to align the icon on the top.